# TOTP app for SL7 (RHEL7), preferably RPM?

Tags: rhel, rpm, scientific-linux, 2-factor-authentication

We are unfortunately stuck with Scientific Linux 7 (a RHEL 7 clone) for a while longer, until we prepare our move to Ubuntu later this year. Our organisation is now also starting to require MFA for email, and we need to try to find a TOTP app suitable for our Linux users (as a fallback option additional to smartphone apps, or for users without smartphones).

**KeePassXC** does have TOTP capability, but sadly the EPEL RPMs only seem to be available for EL8 onwards. If there is a suitable older version somewhere in [the KeePassXC git repo](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/releases) I don't know the appropriate magic to try to find it, unfortunately. As our systems are automatically configured, alternative app formats such as Flatpak, AppImage or snap unfortunately won't work. Does anyone know where a suitable older RPM or, if need be, compatible older source code could be found?

I have also looked into **oathtool**, but its manual is rather cryptic as to how you actually get it to work, and if it really needs all the configuration and additional support scripts [described in nixCraft's instructions for oathtool](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/use-oathtool-linux-command-line-for-2-step-verification-2fa/), it would unfortunately be just far too complicated for our end users to use.

Alternatively, are there other TOTP apps that would be suitable for use with SL7/RHEL7?

Comment: What is cryptic about oathtool? `oathtool -b --totp 'secret'` does it for me. Anyway, you could try asking this at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: also, I think the keepassxc AppImage should work. does it not?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, the current AppImage version complains that the OS doesn't have sufficiently recent Qt (and other) library versions when you try to run it. However, I did some digging on the KeePassXC site, trying older versions a few releases apart until I found one which worked, and then versions between "works" and "doesn't work" until I narrowed it down, and it looks like KeePassXC 2.4.3 is the most recent version which works with SL7.

Comment: [https://github.com/tadfisher/pass-otp](https://github.com/tadfisher/pass-otp) with [https://www.passwordstore.org/](https://www.passwordstore.org/) should work for totp. I'm not familiar with RHEL but pass and pass-otp are pure bash scripts cli tool so it should not be hard to use them on old system. Note **pass-otp is lacking maintenance** and there are some bug fixes not being merged. One noticeable bug fix is [https://github.com/tadfisher/pass-otp/pull/172](https://github.com/tadfisher/pass-otp/pull/172), without this, hotp won't work on newer version of bash.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/dist/Pass-OTP/view/README.pod https://github.com/browserpass/browserpass-extension https://github.com/passff/passff